# Why set the bar so high to approve low-rep edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I heard that only 10k users are allowed to review (and approve) edits done by the little people. Why set it so high, especially if you allow 2k users to edit without approval?

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab/80122#80122

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You heard wrong; to approve post edits you need the same amount of rep as to perform the edits, [2k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). Editing tag wikis is harder, so approving them requires more rep, [5k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (weirdly, this means it *is* possible to be able to approve a tag wiki edit but not be able to edit the tag wiki yourself). 10k lets you see the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?pagesize=15&filter=day) review tab, which lists all edits waiting in the queue

Comment: And how can you approve an edit when you cannot see the suggested edits tab? Does that not effectively make sure that people <10k cannot approve edits? Isn't the OP question still valid?

Comment: @fishinear If you stumble on a post that has a pending suggested edit, you can click the edit link to review it. There's just no easy way to *find* suggested edits without the review tab

Answer (score 5):

No, currently only the 10k users can see a list of all pending edits. But if you happen to bump into a pending edit, [2k is enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work).