# Why set the bar so high for viewing 'suggested edits' review tab?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Considering that I'm allowed to approve edits (2k privilege), why aren't I also allowed to view pending edits (10k privilege)?

**update**: I argued here that it takes an expert to reach 10k, and then someone said it takes mere diligence. Maybe that applies on SO, but it's far harder to reach such a level on a far smaller site like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

**update 2**: I see that [the bar has been lowered to 5k now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sho/105870#105870) :)

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80184/stats-on-suggested-edits

Comment: On sites like unit.se that don't have many questions the mods may be able to keep up with suggested edits themselfs.

Comment: If you participate regularly enough on low-traffic sites like unix.se, you are going to see most of the suggested edits anyway. I know I do. If it was a high traffic site gaining that rep wouldn't be very hard. I asked about this too early on just after earning edit privileges on unix.se, but a little farther down the line I've become convinced that it really makes sense the way it's setup now.

Answer (score 22):

I think 10K is too high to view the pending edits; however we don't wish to have every 2K user going about approving/rejecting everything in sight.

By only letting most users see the edits in questions they choose to look at anyway, I think the results are better.

**Only if pending edits take too long to be acted on, do we need to let more people see the pending edit list.**

Comment: I'm not sure what your argument is here. Also, what are you implying about **we don't wish to have every 2K user going about approving/rejecting everything in sight**. Is approving edits such a sensitive process that even a 2k user isn't trusted enough?

Comment: @Tshepang, it is better for a user with an interest (and hence maybe knowage) about a quesions to be looking at edits.

Comment: Are you suggesting that 2k users generally don't have enough interest and knowledge? I just want to understand you better.

Comment: @Tshepang, I think 2K users have enough interest and knowledge in **some** areas of the site, these tent to be the areas they are active in, so in these areas they will tend to see pending edits in "day to day" usage of the site.

Comment: How does one see pending edits "day to day"? Do I revisit all questions that have a specific tag continually, just to check if there might be pending edits? The only way I'll bump into such pending edits I can think of is by accident, because AFAIK they don't get bumped on the main page (or do they?). As you can see, I can't make sense of this, but if I'm missing anything, please indicate so... be patient with me.

Comment: @Tshepang,  I think you are looking at it from the wrong way round, we don’t care who approves edits, provided they get approved “fast enough”. So a system is needed that has as low a risk as possible while still getting enough people doing the approvals to keep up with the rate that new suggested edits come in. So letting you approve edits is of no value to the site, unless the edits are not getting approved fast enough. Therefore does each suggested edit get found by two 2k+ users quick enough?

Comment: Hm, interesting point you are making.

Comment: As a frequent edit suggester, I would say they definitely get approved plenty fast.

Comment: On SO at least, it's becoming increasingly common for the Suggested Edit queue to be full. I've seen several questions over the last few days and weeks asking why edits can't be submitted, or asking for help in working the queue.

Answer (score 11):

It's also a privilege, meaning, you earn the right to view all pending edits at 10k.

So in that sense, it is a bit of an incentive as well.

Comment: I thought that if I'm allowed to do edits **without** approval, I'm trusted enough. And 10k is an excessively high rep level, and achieved only by experts (meaning I'm counted out).

Comment: @Tshepang: It's hardly fair to say that 10k is only achievable by experts. You could certainly say that it requires due diligence and a lot of time invested in the site, but there are plenty of questions to be answered that don't require a true expert.

Comment: @cody me updated the question

Comment: @Cody Gray: Tshepang is referring to the Unix stack overflow site.  I'd tend to trust his judgment, since he's active there.  I understand some of his frustration.  On Meta, I have a 130 reputation.  I don't even dream of reaching 1,000, let alone 10,000 reputation.  On my most active board, it might be another year or two before I have the chance to reach 10,000 reputation.  So, for me, these high value privileges aren't an incentive.  For me and many others, they are an impossible dream.

Comment: @Gilbert: Consider that at the time I posted that comment, I had a few hundred rep here on Meta, most of which was the result of the +100 points you get for associating accounts with another site. I now have 2k here on Meta. I obviously can't speak for Unix/Linux, as I'm not a member of that site. But I hardly think it's an unattainable goal. That was the only point I was making, that it doesn't require one to be an "expert". I'm neither an expert on programming, nor an expert on the Stack Exchange network--just an average user. A few good answers net large amounts of rep very quickly.

Comment: @Cody Gray:  I didn't notice the date of the question or answer, so I apologize for that.  Still, I see too many people telling others "try harder" to gain reputation points, when they benefited from being pioneers and having much more land (reputation) to grab.

Comment: @Gilbert: I don't think I was a pioneer. I haven't even earned a "Yearling" badge yet. I've only been a member for about 8 months, and only an active participant for 5-6. I understand the complaint that it's *difficult*, but that's why only moderator-level privileges are placed at that level. Not things you need for regular, productive use of the site. I was originally only speaking to the claim that you had to be an *expert* to earn 10k, and I don't think that's true. I know a little bit about Windows programming, and I fake the rest. But thanks, I'll keep your objections in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine for exactly the same reason that viewing the list of questions with close votes is a 10k privilege:

- It means that 10k users (who are more likely to make a good judgement call on whether to reject or approve an edit) will usually get to be among the first to respond to a edit request.
- **It provides an incentive / reward for users earning reputation**