# Statistics on Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's the summary of your own suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/wheres-the-summary-of-your-own-suggested-edits)

I apologize if this question has been asked before. I tried searching for it, but couldn't find anything.

I have 10k+ rep on SO and so I can review suggested edits in the review queue. I was wondering if there was a way to see some data about my votes? As in, how many edits that I voted "Approve" on were approved, how many edits that I voted "Reject" on were rejected, and how many where my vote was overruled?

Perhaps it would be a good way to gauge the "effectiveness" of a user's reviewing skills, and that could come into play when moderator elections come up. A badge for a good review score would also be nice.

Comment: There's http://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits (10k only), but you can't filter that by user

Comment: Currently suggested edits are 10k only, and not filtered by user, but historical edits are public.  Go to http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/[some number], using the method described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/wheres-the-summary-of-your-own-suggested-edits

Comment: This was actually asked before the 'duplicate', however since the other has the bulk of the answers, I'm making this point to that.