# Where's the summary of your own suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, suggested-edits, help

Where can I find my pending/approved/rejected suggested edits? (a bit like the Flagging Summary page)

Comment: This would be great towards knowing how close you are to "Copy Editor", too...

Comment: It looks like you can only get a list of your approved edits, under Activity\Revisions.

Comment: Confirmed.  Approved edits show up in your current activity, but not suggested edits.

Comment: @robert you mean pending ones?

Comment: suggested == pending.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248058/knu?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

I added it in a while back.

Comment: When exactly did you add it? Want to put accurate date [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) :)

Comment: But that page doesen't show the outcome. I created a feature-request: [show-the-outcome-of-suggested-edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230989/)

Comment: @Knu hope they'll keep changing it, you'll get tons of rep :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard just realized they reverted back to the original one.

Answer (score 10):

I think you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50215), your "Editor Stats":

[image: Editor Stats: Knu had 9 edit suggestions approved, and 2 edit suggestions rejected]

---

It's displayed on the suggested edit information page for any of the edits you proposed. Just use your [profile's "activity" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248058/knu?tab=activity) to find your last suggested edit, and open that post. Underneath it, there will be a link to that post's edit history; click that.

[image: edited yesterday by Knu]

Then, find your edit in the edit history, and click the "suggested" hyperlink:

[image: suggested by Knu]

In the [suggested edit page that appears](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/49365), scroll all the way down to the bottom and check the "Editor Stats". It will show the number of edits that you've had approved, the number of edits that you've had rejected, and a list of your recent edit suggestions.

However, it doesn't show pending edits. These are not available for you to look at.

Comment: How can I can tell the difference between a suggested edit and a personal edit in the activity tab? Where are listed the older not-pending suggested edits?

Comment: @Knu: The personal edits are not listed in the "Editor Stats" list. You'll only find those in your activity. As for how to tell the difference, well, they won't have a clickable "suggested" link.

Comment: You don't get it I mean *in the activity tab* itself.

Comment: @Knu: Yeah, you can't. You're not really intended to browse this type of information, so the UI isn't terribly intuitive or full-featured. I've provided the best workaround that there is. Honestly, you shouldn't need to go look at your previously suggested edits. If you're unsure about them, then *don't suggest them* in the first place. That you aren't sure how close you are to earning badges is completely *by-design*, and unlikely to change.

Comment: I am not really interested in that particular badge (sorry) but Id like to have an overall idea of my edit suggestion stats (and check the rejected ones) that's all

Comment: @Knu: The page I've linked to gives you an overall idea of your edit suggestion stats. That's exactly what it's for. It gives the number of *all* the edits you've had approved and *all* of them that you've had rejected. I'm sorry it's not easier to get to, but it *is* there and you *can* find it if you want to. (Not a problem that you're uninterested in the badge. It's just that there are lot of people that are.)

Comment: Is it even pullable using [data](http://data.stackexchange.com)? //off topic// Why [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50215) was rejected? (his code can't work without my modification)

Comment: @Knu: No idea, I don't use the data dump. That edit was rejected because it's generally discouraged to change the code posted by other users. If you know a reason it needs to be modified to work in IE, you should leave them a comment explaining your concerns. If they agree with you, then they can make the edit themselves. Or they can ask you to edit and approve it since it's their own answer. As a matter of general policy, unless I see a comment thread where the original poster approves it, I will reject edits made to code. That's a much bigger deal than grammar/spelling fixes or retags.

Comment: Either this answer has been so overcome by events of the past six years that it is now (mostly?) wrong, or it is so unclear that I can’t figure out how to get it to work.   The fact that all the links are broken suggests that the answer is broken.   Can somebody fix this, one way or the other?