# Not approved edits retained for editors reference

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where’s the summary of your own suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/wheres-the-summary-of-your-own-suggested-edits)

I think it would be good to provide access to all one's edits, regardless of whether they are approved or not, as I (for one) don't spend time making arbitrary changes, only ones which I believe make something clearer, or more correct for myself and others.

Could adding edits that were done, but not approved, be added to a user's profile. This way, edits that one thinks are helpful would still (at least) be available to this person for future use / reference.

Comment: All of your suggested edits can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1126551/user66001?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: status-completed?

Comment: Btw when you suggest an edit and [it is rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1112288) you shouldn't just [suggest it again](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1112393).

Comment: @Servy, despite the fact that it clearly worked the second time?  Not that it should have, mind you...

Comment: Thanks everyone for jumping on this so far, and alerting me to my lack of looking around a bit. @Servy - I don't believe I did what you claim (though lack of timestamps (BTW - Why doesn't this edit have a time stamp?) leaves me with just my word to stand on), what I remember happening is making an edit, then soon after realizing that there was a grammar error that would also be good to fix, and re-editing my edit. I certainly didn't see the rejection, until now.

Comment: @user66001 The timestamps are there.  If you hover over any time in SE sites that's given in days/hours/etc. it will give the exact time to the second.  You proposed the second edit over an hour after the first was rejected.  This clearly shows that you did *exactly* what I'm claiming.  It may have been unintentional, but you still did it.

Comment: @Servy - Thanks, good to know about the alt tag containing the timestamps. I am more used to the time being stated more precisely, like above with (currently) "edited 4 hours ago". Sorry, also, I stated that I didn't believe, not to the level of saying that I didn't, like your _exactly_ makes me think you feel I did. I still maintain that I didn't see see the first edit being refused, but as there is many different reviewers out there, there is going to be many different opinions, and I have previously suggested an edit to a answer that had the right idea, but was completely wrong

Comment: ... which had it been refused first, I would have tried at least once or twice again, to try and find someone who considered it differently to the first judges. The history is still there, should someone be curious / not like what one put down, they can counter edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been implemented.

Go find the `Activity` tab of your profile, you'll find all your suggested edits listed there. You can specifically filter on just edits, the filter is called `suggestions`:

[image: suggested edits filter]