# Display status of suggested edits in StackExchange inbox

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)
>   [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history)

While my recent proposal turned question [Not approved edits retained for editors reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/not-approved-edits-retained-for-editors-reference) has been answered, just realised that the activity tab doesn't make it easy to tell what has been rejected, or approved. Is there somewhere else this can be seen, or can I suggest a change?

Comment: @animuson - Yes, I agree (Am no good at searching today!) Personally, would think the two issues be seperate threads, though, so perhaps this community could let this stay open to address your issue 2?

Comment: although this is a duplicate of a previously rejected feature (and it has been mentioned numerous times, but I'm too lazy to find the other).. I agree that *something* needs done to notify the editor of the suggested edit status.  Maybe the notification bar isn't the right place, but there needs to be a more obviously place to see the status.