# Position / Styling of Linked Questions

Tags: discussion, design, linked-questions

What does the community think about the positioning of the Linked Questions list.

For me, I associate content on the side of a page as navigation / ancillary information, not to link to important content.

Not sure where / how it would otherwise be best displayed though - Perhaps just a change of colour, or temporary highlighting (Like what you have when you visit a permalinked page).

Answer (score 7):

I would certainly want linked questions to be better visible than now.

- In an example shown at screen shot below, I for one would be more interested in seeing linked questions than stuff about community bulletin, people chatting and weekly newsletter ad.

  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRrRL.png]

Design challenge here is how to address cases when there are **many linked questions** so that their list takes a lot of vertical  space - for example, like in the [Recent feature changes...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773) super-hit.

I find linked questions important, but on the other hand I wouldn't want them to push stuff about bulletin, chat and newsletter completely out of my sight. Luckily, idea of possible solution for mentioned challenge is provided in that very super-hit.

The list is of limited size and ends with [see more linked questions…](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f59445%2f*%22&lq=1) link.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR4O3.png]

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen this happen on occasion, and also feel it a worth improvement (Perhaps a time limited hover link drop down, so that you stay on the same page, but don't have to manually toggle the list to see other content in the meantime), notwithstanding my opinion that linked questions should be displayed in some other fashion more visible to those who don't usually look in the sidebar for this kind of thing.

Comment: Is there a glossary of SE terms - [super-hit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165773)??