# Get vote counts on related questions on SO too!

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

I just noticed this great new feature on meta:

[image: New votecounts!]

Can we have this on the trilogy too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's coming. The devs like to test everything first on meta before pushing it out to the main sites.

Comment: @Mysticial: Yay!

Comment: It's a Meta test for now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172537/some-small-changes-to-related-questions

Comment: How about we don't? Too distracting...

Comment: @Yannis: I like it. It makes related questions useful again.

Comment: It does make the related questions useful, but at the cost of stealing focus. I'm not convinced the benefits outweigh the cost.

Comment: @Yannis, I think stealing a little focus might be good, in that it will help people maybe see that the question has already been asked, and keep some duplicates from happening.  By keeping it in a light shade (not having green for accept) it isn't awfully distracting, just takes a little bit to get used to.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I think my proposal to just adjust the related algorithm so highly voted questions get priority in the sorting will achieve the same result without the unnecessary distraction. Furthermore, duplicates are not _that_ common, why do we need a feature that's always on and always distracting, but only useful when hunting for dupes? Can you think of any other use for showing the vote count? Because if it's only dupe hunting, this simply isn't worth it. Even for sites where dupes are common, it's not like we have a problem finding them quickly...

Comment: @Yannis, I have no good response to that, because I only use it for dupe-checking myself.  Not sure there really is another reason.

Comment: @LanceRoberts If this gets build, I'll probably write a small userscript and turn it off, so it's not really a big deal for me. I'm just not convinced it's needed, and I'd prefer it if the team concentrated on the various open feature requests that come from the community instead. If I'm not horribly mistaken, the community didn't really ask for this.

Answer (score 2):

Meta is often used as a testing site, once they figure the bugs are worked out and that they like it, they'll roll it out.  It looks great to me.

Here's [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172537/some-small-changes-to-related-questions) to look at on this topic.