# Indication of accepted answer in the related and linked posts section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, related-questions, linked-questions

I see that "related" and "linked" posts section (on the right side) shows score/vote count adjacent to each post's title. To be consistent with vote count display in other areas of the site, I suggest that the 'vote count' box should be filled with a different color to indicate if that post has an accepted answer.

Here is the **current** display of "related" section:

[image]

Tooltip text **earlier** was: `3 votes, with an accepted answer`. Now there is no indication whatsoever.

For cross reference, here is how 'vote count' box is displayed under "Questions that may already have your answer" section:

[image]

Comment: +1 that would be really useful

Comment: [We already tried that, and it was overwhelmingly distracting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172537/some-small-changes-to-related-questions/172584#comment512083_172537)

Comment: @Laura sure I understand. However, instead of green fill/shade please try changing the text color. A slightest difference would suffice.

Comment: @Laura - So this was status completed in that the accepted answer indication was completely removed? Please at least return the "with an accepted answer" tooltip (or conversely "without an accepted answer"). It doesn't have to mention anything about the vote count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the Stack Exchange sites, such as Server Fault and Programmers, do provide an indication if questions have an accepted answer (screenshot below).

[image: Related section on Server Fault]

The CSS class `.answered-accepted`, responsible to display this marker, is also present in the CSS of Meta Stack Overflow but currently it is not used.

```
.answered-accepted {
   background: #737967;
}
```

can be changed to:

```
.answered-accepted {
   border: 2px dotted #3D5509 !important;
}
```

I believe this indication of accepted answer will not be too overpowering / distracting and will also serve the purpose.

**Update**: This request is now complete. Following CSS was added on MSE, which gives a greenish background to the scores box to show that the post contains an accepted answers.

```
.answered-accepted {
  background: #e4f9d3 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we already use `.answered-accepted` class for accepted questions, we just need to add the following style on that class:

```css
.answered-accepted {
   background: #5B9058 !important;
   color: #fbfabd !important;
}
```

instead of:

```css
.answered-accepted {
   background: #737967;
   color: #fbfabd;
}
```

This will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel like perhaps add a `:hover` CSS style with green shading would be good. I just tried looking at related questions and it is frustrating waiting for the tooltip (even though it isn't that long) to know whether or not there is an accepted answer.

If the user's cursor is hovering over the link, it means his attention is there anyways. Perhaps that can be a medium between the two? It wouldn't be distracting when users are normally browsing the site and it would be nice because then they could simply glide their cursor over the Related questions and see which ones turn up as green or have some green shading to the vote count.