# Does displaying the votes of linked questions have any advantages?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, related-questions

Recently, the related questions are displayed along with their scores in the sidebar. What advantage does that offer ?

The relevance of a related question to the current question is not directly dependent on the score of the linked post. A question having a bad score could be more relevant to the current question, than one having a better score. It might also bias users to the relevance of the post, as well as, make users stay away from low voted posts, even though that post maybe the most *relevant* post displayed. The score just appears to be a distracting element in the otherwise clean user interface.

Comment: Maybe you should have your input [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172537/208592)

Comment: The score offers an advantage on where to *start* looking for a good close target. The one with +48 is more likely than the one with -6.

Comment: @BoPersson That alone does not warrant a distraction developed into the UI. Again, a post may be an exact duplicate of a related post at -6 or one at +48. The score is irrelevant here, its the content of the post that matters.

Comment: It does to me. I would look at the +48 question *first*. If that looks like a close enough duplicate, I would vote to close. Otherwise I will continue looking for a better target, saving the -6 question for last.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does. If I'm looking at a question, and I see two related questions that look applicable to my situation, I want to visit the one with +20, not the closed one with -8, right? Without these vote-counts, related questions is like trying to find a neadle in a haystack (albeit, a small one).

Comment: What if the -8 one is an *exact* match whereas the +20 is a *close* match? Will you look beyond the first good/high score question?

Comment: @AshRj: what good will it do me to look at an exact match that has -8 and no answers, rather than a higher up voted, answered question?

Comment: To close a question as a duplicate, the sufficient condition is that it should have been asked before. If the question had been downvoted previously, there is a fair chance that the current one will be downvoted as well.