# Add a "more" link to the Related Questions

Tags: feature-request, search, similar-questions

On the side of posted Stack Exchange website questions, there is a side bar that tells you the same site questions that are linked in the post (if any), and below it, there is a "Related" questions box that must do some sort of indexing of the page and finds similar questions. I am proposing a simple "more questions similar to this" link at the bottom of the "Related" tab section.

[image: More questions link]

### Possible Implications

#### Popup Box

It could show a popup box similar to the interface of flagging a question/answer. This would also be similar to the "duplicate" tab inside of the flagging UI. It could show the question title, the votes, and an excerpt of the question

#### Search Feature

It would take you to the site search engine, similar to clicking on the tag score of a user. I prefer this method, because it would add a new feature to the search engine. The callout would look something like `issimilar:[question#]`. The search engine would take consider the question title, and the question text. It could also consider the tags, but that shouldn't be a huge part of the search. You would also still be able to use `[tag]` in the search. So for this question, it would look like this

[image]

Comment: +1 for the search idea.

Comment: I don't understand how "more question similar to this" is different than the existing "related".

Comment: related (not a dupe): [Position / Styling of Linked Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163188/165773)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha to have more related questions.

Comment: I agree, having more related questions would be very useful, either when looking for duplicate or when looking for more information.