# Changing the placement of the "Similar Questions" panel

Tags: discussion

I was recently trying to find the answer to a question I had to a question about the implementation of the Linux kernel linked list. I searched for a bit using keywords like pointer arithmetic and (char *) vs. (int *) but of course they were all generic and not helpful. I finally typed out almost the entirety of the question but the left the title blank as I was unsure how to phrase it. I happened to glance to the side and saw the "Similar Questions" panel and realized someone had asked the exact question I was wondering about.

I think there was a very high chance that I wouldn't have noticed the relevant question at all. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the placement of the similar questions panel on the right of the screen. Since English reads left to right my theory is that most of the time is spent looking at the left side of the screen when doing significant amounts of typing. Another theory is that I've been conditioned by facebook to look at the left for a lot of the things I click on, whereas ads are normally placed on the right hand side. So it would be better to have the panel on the left hand side. Since the similar questions seem to actually be incredibly relevant once the body of the question is typed in, it seems that optimizing the panel placement for maximal viewing would greatly reduce duplicates.

Comment: related: [Position / Styling of Linked Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163188/position-styling-of-linked-questions)