# Show (duplicate) status next to titles on right Linked/Related Questions panels

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, related-questions, linked-questions

When a user see a list of  Linked/Related Questions on right panel, it will be useful to have the word [duplicate] visible immediately after title. It will help to understand why the questions linked and should I look at them.

Note that if the question has too many links, there is a link at the bottom "see more linked questions" and it opens full size page, where [duplicate] status is shown after the title of each duplicate question. So the change will make linked questions presentation consistent.

Somehow related suggestions to make easier see duplicates:
[Show questions closed as being duplicates on the initial question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157517/show-questions-closed-as-being-duplicates-on-the-initial-question).
[Show list of duplicates of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313699/show-list-of-duplicates-of-the-question)

Comment: @shadowWizard The request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126460/why-doesnt-the-related-question-list-show-that-questions-are-closed is similar, but different. This suggestion is about duplicated linked questions, not about closed related questions. So the use case for them is slightly different.

Comment: Duplicate is closed, just one type of closure.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, it's better to have specific state "duplicate" shown instead of less descriptive generic "closed"

Comment: This is almost obvious, in my opinion. If done, I am pretty sure they will show "duplicate" instead of "closed" anyway. No need for special request.