# How to find all my edited questions/answers which are in pending approval(Queue)?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have edited someone's question in `stackoverflow.com`. As I don't have enough reputation to edit a question/answer with out approval, my edit has been in queue for waiting approval. I closed that tab at that time but now I want to check whether my edit has been in queue or not. How can I check that?

I know in my profile page I have an optioned called '-- Posts Edited' but I'm sure it will show only when my edit has been approved.

[image]

But I want to check what are all the questions I have edited are in **QUEUE** Is it possible?

Note: This question might looks like a duplicate of [Where's the summary of your own suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/wheres-the-summary-of-your-own-suggested-edits) but my requirement is to see all the question which were declined or in Queue.

[image]

Here I can see only the approved edits/rejected edits. But I want to see `edits in Queue` just like `approved edits` :)

Comment: ...also contained within the FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/168244)

Comment: I see in your screen shot an rejected edit, and if it is in the queue, you see pending edit. There is no further filtering possible

Comment: @rene Edited my question as per my requirement.

Comment: @rene Yes. You are correct :)

Comment: @rene Me too marked this question as a duplicate as said by you :) Sorry for the trouble :(