# Can users who have 2000+ rep see the suggested edit queue in the top bar?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Someone said only users who have 10000+ rep can use the suggest edit queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only 5k+ users can see the number of pending suggested edits, and the queue page.

However at all times you can approve pending suggested edits on your own questions.

[See this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab) for more information as to why this is the case.

Comment: For the users who have 2000-10000 rep, how them find a suggest edit needs to be reviewed?

Comment: @Roy: The only way to find it is by browsing questions. When you come across one for which an edit has been proposed, the `edit` link under the question will read either `edit (0)` or `edit (1).

Comment: @Cody Gray: I only saw edit (0) , and nerver saw `edit (1). What difference between edit (0) and `edit (1)?

Comment: @Roy: The number in parentheses is the number of approve votes that the edit has received so far. When it is first suggested, you'll see `edit (0)`. When someone has voted to approve/disapprove it, you'll see `edit (1)`. For a few milliseconds between the time two users have voted on it and the time that it is removed from the queue, I imagine you would see `edit (2)`.