# Under-10k users can view /suggested-edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

I recently saw the Suggested Edits stream: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/ mentioned in a Meta discussion, and I was intrigued by the idea, so I checked it out. It seems to be a 10k user feature, because I get Page Not Found for that exact address*, but other than the fact that I have to manually input index numbers (using good old binary search :) --

```
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/45000    # Nope, doesn't work...
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/40000    # Too low, already approved...
# Time passes...
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/40922    # Ah ha! The latest; still pending!
```

I was perfectly able to view and approve/improve edits once I found the right spot in the stream.

I'm aware that, being over 3k, I have the ability to approve suggested edits when I stumble across them in the normal course of viewing questions, so there's no real problem here as far as "power", but I just thought I'd bring it up in case it's not meant to be this way.

---

*and all the users who were doing the approving seemed to be over 10k.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85393/can-users-who-have-2000-rep-see-the-suggested-edit-queue-in-the-top-bar

Comment: Thanks random. I'll close this as soon as I can accept Daniel's answer to thank him.

Comment: Or should I just leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested edits are visible by all users, as I understand it (at least, on another Stack site where I have <200 rep I can see them).  They show up in the revision history with a hyperlinked "suggested by" next to their name so you can see who approved/rejected the edit.  It's so that you can see the "full" revision history with all involved parties, which everyone had been able to do prior to the suggested edit system.

Comment: Got it. by-design then. Thanks! /taps fingers waiting to be able to accept answer...