# How does StackOverflow distribute the pending edits to users who have 10000+ rep?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Can anyone who have 10,000+ reputation receive all pending edits in suggest edit queue, or do only the users who have 10,000+ reputation and are experts for the question (e.g. they earned more than a number rep in the tags which used by the question) see the pending edits?

What about the close/reopen/delete voting?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85393/can-users-who-have-2000-rep-see-the-suggested-edit-queue-in-the-top-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when there are enough items in the pending edit queue a link appears up in the bar at the top (the page can also be reached via the 10K mod tools). A user can then browse the pending edits and approve or reject the ones they review (or ignore them if they cannot make a decision). It takes two votes for a pending edit to be either rejected or approved.

For the close/open/delete voting, you can read about the required rep level here: https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Edit:
in answer to your comment... I'm not quite sure I understand the question you're asking now but I'll still try to answer it. You can read more about Closing/Open votes here: [Cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)

With deletion votes there is a vote number threshold that must be met before the question is deleted, that threshold depends on the upvotes of the question (I'm not sure if the number of answers is also factored in). For example, this question [*Why is Git better than Subversion?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion) still requires another 64 votes to delete it - in reality it will probably never cross that threshold.

Comment: And how about close/reopen/delete voting? all users who can access 10K mod tools, will receive all the votes?

Comment: Check my edit...

Comment: Yes, number of votes needed for deletion depends on the sum of the scores of question and all its answers.

Answer (score 2):

The pending edits are all viewed from the users with the privilege to see them, independently from the score users have on the tags used in the questions being edited.

That is true also for other pages: I can see the questions that received votes to be closed in the 10k tools page, and the questions voted to be deleted, independently from the score I have in the tags used in those questions.

Answer (score 0):

For pending deletes it appears you see the whole list (I can't recall it ever being more than 20).

For close/delete/... voting you expand from the top 5 to a longer list (but often not all with some votes).

For review you get a random 30, with a link to get another random 30 (and this does mean sometimes getting the same one again).