# How can I help with suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why set the bar so high for viewing 'suggested edits' review tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab)

This question was inspired by [Do we need a Bat-Signal on Meta, calling in help when the edit queue is full?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129850/164367)

I currently have 2696 Rep on SO, which gives me the privilege of editing questions and answers.

Occasionally I open a question/answer to edit it to find a suggested edit waiting for review, it seems I am able to vote to accept/reject the answer.

I haven't found a way of listing suggested edits that are waiting for review, but maybe I've missed it. I couldn't find anything with a search.

If there is currently no way of a user with sub 5k rep getting a list of suggested edits then maybe it should be made available. It would certainly help with the current suggested edit back log.

I have added the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag in case this does not already exist.

The linked questions do help, but don't answer the "How can I help" part.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85393/can-users-who-have-2000-rep-see-the-suggested-edit-queue-in-the-top-bar

Comment: Ahh, didn't find that. My SO search foo needs improvment.

Comment: You can vote-to-close your question if you feel that those answer your question.

Comment: Note that you now get access to the queue well below 10k. I forgot whether it's 3k or 5k, though.

Comment: The linked questions do help, but don't answer the "How can I help" part.

Comment: @vascogotlost: Well, the sneaky way is to find the end of the queue by messing with the URL--eg current end of queue is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3154) on MSO. But I suggest you stay away from the queue till you get to 5k

Comment: @DanielFischer: It's at 5k

Answer (score 2):

Lucky for you, **there's an app for that**™!

[Suggested Edits Queue for Mere Mortals](https://stackapps.com/questions/3087/suggested-edits-queue-for-mere-mortals)

From that post on Stack Apps:

> This Java command-line app gives you access to the Suggested Edits
>   queue using the Stack Exchange 2.0 API. It is ideally suited for users
>   in the 2000 <= reputation < 5000 range.

Since it's Java, all you need is the Java Runtime Environment to run this app.  Then you can start pounding away at that suggested edits queue =)

Comment: Note: Contrary to what the readme says, the "duplicates" parameter appears to be required.  I get a `NullPointerException` if I leave that out.  Works great otherwise.