# Reject and improve: please allow editing from the pre-suggested-edit version

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

This is a continuation of [Do we need a 'reject and improve' button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button). In the previous episode, we obtained a way to say “the suggestion is not helpful, you don't get reputation for suggesting it”. But as a reviewer, when I see a suggested edit that is not helpful on a question that needs editing, I need to:

1. Click on "Improve".
2. Untick the “suggested edit was helpful” box.
3. Bring up the post source, copy the original source into the edit box.
4. Make the good edit I wanted to make.

Step 3 is really cumbersome. When a question has been edited before, there is a way to bring back the last published version (or any prior version), through the "Rev" box at the top of the page. But this box does not appear when the post has never been edited before.

Please show the revision list on every suggested edit improve page, or provide some other reasonable way of rejecting an edit and improving the post.

*P.S. [And please fix the UI annoyances. We don't have enough people reviewing suggested edits on Stack Overflow as it is; don't make it even less attractive than it could be.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow)*

Comment: You can actually do this by going to the post's revision history and clicking the edit link on whatever revision you want to edit from. The pending suggested edit gets rejected by Community.

Comment: Regarding not enough people reviewing suggested edits, 2k+ users can review them, but only if they are looking at a post that has a suggested edit. Until 10k, users have no way to acess the queue of suggestions. Potential feature-request? [Related #1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85393/167443) and [Related #2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80070/167443)

Comment: @Jim Isn't it until 5k?

Comment: @animuson Ok, that's another cumbersome method (especially with the default UI that doesn't show the revision history link — I use an extension that shows it all the time, but I don't have this extension on every browser).

Comment: @Bart It appears it is, according to the posts I just linked (edited in after your comment). However, I've only got 5k+ on one site, and don't see the queue there, so I assumed it was part of the 10k tools

Comment: @Jim It's 5k, but you have to go for it: it's a new tab in `/review`. There are already several feature requests about this, including [one of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128889/please-make-the-pending-suggested-edit-indicator-visible-at-5k-rep).

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was in /review. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The "Improve" button has been split into two choices, "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit". The latter button will accomplish what you want, filling in the original revision so you can edit that.

As a side note, though, neither button contains the "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox anymore, so if you want to reject the suggested edit while still editing on top of it, you have to use the "Improve Edit" button and copy over the changes to the "Reject and Edit" form.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the original version appears to be the way this now works, however it's just as annoying when the suggestion was good and I *wanted* to start from that. This really needs to be ***a SWITCH*** for the improver. The "edit was helpful" checkbox would work just fine as far as I'm concerned. Move it to the top and make it choose between starting from the pre- or post-suggestion text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Just today, I tried editing a posts with a pending edit with and without `?improve=true`. The version with the suggested edit came up, with no way to select the original as is.