# Raise the suggested edit vote limit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

In response to this question: 
[Why are suggested edit votes limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited)

Raise the suggested edit vote limit.  Currently it is at 30 per day.  I would suggest 60, but any number above 30 would help.

**Advantage**:  More users could vote on suggested edits.  This would allow edits to be approved faster and keep the queue of suggested edits low.

**Disadvantage**:  Expands the potential for abuse.

In my opinion the potential abuse of a 10k user propping up a sockpuppet with peer edits is much smaller than the benefits of allow more users to peer review.

**Edit**:  An example.  I noticed [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/63919) and that it had already been approved once.  It really needed to be rejected, however, I was out of votes.  I posted it on meta's chat and two people responded to reject it.  If I could have rejected it myself, I don't think I would be as concerned and would have needed to ask others to reject it.

Comment: It's not just for sockpuppets, that limit.

Comment: When tagging a meta question [feature-request], it is customary to explain how that request will add value.  "More users could vote on suggested edits" is a feature; what is the benefit?

Comment: @Robert, added some more detail.

Comment: @Grace, looking at the question asking why there is a limit.  There are no answers, but the comments suggest the limit is for sock-puppetry.  Is there another reason?

Comment: Technically you'd only need 2k to do the sockpuppet thing, since you'd know which posts your sock suggested an edit on

Comment: @Michael, you are right.  Then if that truly is the reason for the limit, then just increase it for 10K users.

Comment: It's a general rate limiting thing as well, topped off with the fact it prevents an otherwise uncontrolled stream of reputation and edits from a sub 2k user. It doesn't *have* to be your sockpuppet, but much like you can only vote for a person 30-40 times in one day, or you can only vote to close 24-48 times a day, you have a limit on the number of suggested edit approvals you can make. It's both a factor to prevent one person running the whole shipyard, and also as a convenient method to at least mitigate the flow of approvals to a single user by a single user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It needs to be raised because from time to time the edit queue limit is reached and no one else can submit more edits until someone clears the queue.  I just noticed it full a few minutes ago.  If approvers had more votes, the queue would not fill up as often

Answer (score 3):

I'm all for raising the limit above 30; it pains me to see good suggested edits sitting around for an hour and unable to do anything about it. (Well, I could always just hit the *Improve* button and do the edit myself, but if someone else worked on making the edit, I think they ought to get their +2.)

But not too high -- running out of votes and suggested edit votes is a good reminder to go to bed.