# Increase Edit Votes for 10k+ Users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

[It has been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95931/raise-the-suggested-edit-vote-limit) [several times recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited) to increase the edit vote limits (with no official response that I can find).  I think **at least** 10k users should get more edit votes.

**Advantages**

- Clear up more suggested edits.  At the moment we are around 50 pending approval.  I've seen it as high as 70-80 and never under 20 in the past week or two.
- Limiting this to 10k users will enable the people who can see ALL the suggested edits to review them more quickly and efficiently
- Encourage editing from lower-rep users (who appear to be doing a lot of editing work now).  **Bear in mind editing is mostly thankless, but these guys get a little rep for every approved edit!**

**Disadvantages**

- Possible abuse via sockpuppets, I guess, but how likely is a 10k+ user to have a sock puppet?
- ????

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm suggesting 10k+ rep users get more than 30 votes to cast per day on suggested edits.

Comment: I remember bumping into you yesterday while a user was trying to edit out ***all*** the content from the answers on his post, you helped reject the edits. There was one answer left afterwards with a pending edit and only 1 reject vote - was that when you ran out of votes? Just curious, because I had the same idea at that point when I ran out of votes.

Comment: Right now the number of unapproved edits is at 14.

Comment: @Wesley - Yep! Then I saw like 50 again today and decided to make this post.

Comment: @Paulo - My estimates were off.  It's back up to 24 now.  It's still a lot.

Comment: And another reason - **It's 9am here and I am out of votes for the day!**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited/102223#102223

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We already increased the # of suggested edit votes from 30 to 40 (on Stack Overflow *only*) but I don't want to go any higher.

The point of the limit is to get vote *diversity*; the same 2 or 3 people approving all suggested edits is insufficiently distributed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the right solution. 30 edits a day isn't that low, especially if you **take the time to improve them** and do other things on the posts you spot (upvote, downvote, vote to close, …). [I've written more on this on the associated discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited/102238#102238).

It would be better to **spread the load**: keep the limit as it is, and [open the queue to more users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab), at least on Stack Overflow where it takes two votes to approve or reject an edit. Moving the reputation threshold to 6000 would almost double the number of potential eyeballs.