# How do the review limits work?

Tags: support, review, rate-limiting

I got the brand new Custodian badge today for reviewing posts. Inspired by that, I reviewed some more suggested edits. Now I ran into a limit:

> You have no more suggested edit votes today; come back in x hours.

How is that limit calculated? I made 61 reviews today which seems to be some calculated limit.

I searched for an answer on meta but found nothing helpful.

Comment: I believe you reviewed ( approved/reject ) 50 suggested edit, that's why you got that message. I manually counted them in your profile.

Comment: You can vote on 50 suggested edits per (UTC) day, no more. It's the same for close votes (if you have enough rep to be able to VTC at all). If those are used, no more voting on these until the next day.

Comment: In the old queue, one can review them even if run out of votes by improving the post.

Comment: @DanielFischer I only get 20 not 50... Is it a discrimination against handsome yet humble guys like myself?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, absolutely. (No, that was before the new review queues got everybody and their dog to review. The suggested edits queue was almost perpetually full and the handful of people reviewing needed more votes [the limit was raised from 40 to 50 in spring, March or April]. Then the new review queues came about promising easy gold badges for those clicking fast enough, and the limit was cut to 20 soon after to limit the damage a single robo-approver could do per day.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure I see the point of robo-approving. You'll say that it's because of the golden badge **but** (and correct me if I'm wrong) what's the point of a **wow-oh-my-God-golden-badge** if it's awarded for an achievement that is mediocre? The badge has only real meaning if people respect the means of obtaining it. Or am I figuring incorrectly?

Comment: @Konrad Congrats for not seeing the point. But the badge count in the flair doesn't distinguish between badges you got for great achievements and those you get for mediocre achievements (like Fanatic). So for the viewer, a gold badge is a gold badge. If you follow through to the profile, you can see `k` of the gold badges are for review tasks, but that still doesn't tell you whether it was for clicking Approve for each suggested edit seen, or for carefully considering each, skipping so many, editing so many others, ... . So if you're the kind of person to want the badge for others to see, ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't that be avoided (at least partially) if the small tests that pop out every now and then (very annoying because you get nothing for the work) would lead to suspension of editing right for, say, a week, if failed for instance three times on the same day?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't know if the suggested edits queue has honeypot tests [I'm not sure about the close votes queue either]. In those queues that have honeypot tests, failing too many in a too short time will - as of a couple of days ago - get you banned from the queue for a week (or so). But that's a very recent development, the rate-limiting came first.

Comment: Suggested Edits does seem to have honeypot tests, I passed one earlier this month.

Comment: @DanielFischer Old thread, but I hit two honeypot tests today.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[As Jeff notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited/102223#102223),

> We really want vote diversity here, so that's the point of the limits

The limits in place are currently determined in two ways:

- **Per-queue hard limits**: after 20 reviews in a given queue<sup>*</sup>, you're done for the day - if you want to continue reviewing, you can switch to a different queue.
- **Queue-specific limits on actions**: certain actions are rate-limited regardless of whether they're performed from /review. If you've reached the limit on an action deemed critical for a queue, you'll be locked out for the day (but you can switch to a different queue that doesn't require this action). Examples:

  - Close / do not close votes (Close queue)
  - Delete votes / flags (Low Quality queue)
  - Up/Down votes (First Posts / Late Answers)

#### Related: [Why are suggested edit votes limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited)

<sup>*<sub>Doubled for queues with large backlogs.</sub></sup>

Comment: Anyway the last week I had constantly more than 50 reviews per day. I think that **improvments** does not count as review for the limit but it seems to count for the statistics. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I can understand the new limits, but I hope there come's a sliding limit for users that provide good reviews.

Comment: @BenBrocka, it only takes 50 days for 1000 reviews.

Comment: hmm .. just was surprised by a limit of 20 in the late answers queue, especially since looking at stats the top reviewers today have 40 - intermediary on changing policy or what is the reason for the difference?

Comment: per my testing of late answers queue, limit of 20 is in the ballpark. I would consider increasing it to 30-40 for users with Reviewer badge (250+ reviews) and to 100-200 for users with Steward badge (1000+ reviews)

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe oh, right, math

Comment: @shog9 - does the 20 review per queue, per day limit also include suggested edits (for example) I choose to skip?

Comment: No, skipped reviews don't count @Kev

Comment: What are these "do not close votes" that are "rate-limited regardless of whether they're performed from /review"? I thought "Leave Open" is an action that can only be taken from within the review.

Comment: The limits should be increased in some cases. Reviewers are a scarce resource. In the absence of negative effects (i.e., bad reviews), there's no reason to arbitrarily stop someone at 20 questions. If Stack Overflow ever has more reviewers than questions, then revisit the issue. (And I won't spend effort in H&I. The workflows are poorly designed, and I am not wasting time on the convoluted workflows to close a question).

Comment: The limits double if the queue is over some threshold (varies by site, but pretty low on SO), @jww. Every queue is also limited by various per-day vote limits, so unless you're one of the rare reviewers who likes editing there are only so many *actionable* items that can be reviewed without increasing one of those as well (some of which are tied into the type of posts voted on or your reputation, so this gets complicated in a hurry). Also of course, most reviewers don't use most of their reviews; we've always had much better results increasing the number of reviewers than increasing the cap.

Comment: @Shog9 May i ask you? How come Just Code can have 38 reviews today? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats, i only can have twenty.

Comment: When there are more than 150 tasks awaiting review, the limit is double for that queue, @U9-Forward

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks so much for telling me, i understand now.