# Only 20 daily votes on suggested edits? When and why?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the review limits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147973/how-do-the-review-limits-work)

Before April 20<sup>th</sup> 2012 each user had 40 daily votes for reviewing suggested edits. From that day until today/yesterday/two days ago each user had [50 daily votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129894/152859).

Now I noticed users have only meager 20 votes per day.

[image: screenshot]

Can someone point on the time of change and explain the reason behind this? Especially now that 3-5 votes are required for every suggested edit, this will most likely lead to ever growing queue.

Comment: If this keeps the "rythm" of the suggested edits as it is now, I'm all for it. The queue is still shallow, but at least you get more than 1/2 second to actually look at the edits before a horde of hasty badge-hunters blindly click on the buttons.

Comment: related: [How do the review limits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147973/165773)

Comment: @gnat thanks, didn't see that one. Actually it's a dupe as the answer there also answers this one.

Answer (score 23):

The limit used to be 30. It was increased to 40, then 50, because the queue was always full. Thanks (but no thanks) to the new injection of serial approvers, the queue is now emptied very quickly, so there is no need to have such a high limit.

A lower limit reduces the damage any one person can do, which isn't much help since it also reduces the amount any one person can genuinely help.

A lower limit increases the time it takes for serial approvers to get their coveted badge. Maybe they'll get bored? I hope so, but doubt it — I have seen people suggest exactly 500 (mostly bad) edits in quick succession to get the Copy Editor badge, so there will always be people who are patient enough to game the system.

All in all, I think lowering the number of review votes per day is reasonable: they should be adjusted with the number of edits to review. I expect the limit will be raised again if the queue is full. I myself ran into the limit for the first time yesterday; before that I don't think I'd made 20 reviews in any one day since the review rehaul caused the queue not to be almost always nearly full.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point of official post telling it was 30? Couldn't find it..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/77785/revisions, young padawan

Comment: Oh my... o-O :/