# Where can I find the official documentation on review?

Tags: support, review, documentation, limits

On Stack Overflow you can make reviews, but there is a limit. This limit is not static.
Since I began reviewing, rules governing the review limit has changed **a lot**!

Where can I find the last *updated* rules on reviews?

Comment: hm I'd rather would expect these changes to be reflected in [Recent feature changes...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) but as of now, there's nothing about review limit changes

Comment: I guess that since the review queues are relatively new, things are being tweaked as needed.

Comment: Things also depend on the current state of the queue in question. On SO, the close and low-quality queues are currently quite large, so the limit on reviews has been bumped up from 20 to 40 for just those queues to help clear them faster.

Comment: @jonsca I'm looking for a more detailed documentation. Not just some partial response. Maybe only devs working on reviews limit can tell us how ALL rules are applied...

Comment: @Stephan I think that all that needs to be clarified by Shog9 there would be the "40" rule, which I think applies for any queue that has greater than 1000 items in it.

Comment: For better or worse, it's not always easy to come up with "official documentation" for features on SE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Recent feature changes...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/165773)** have been updated with details reflecting current state of affairs:

> - 2012-10-19: [Review actions limits have been changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981/165773): after 20 reviews in a given queue, you're done for the day - if you want to continue reviewing, you can switch to a different queue. Limit is doubled for queues with large backlogs.