# Link underlining vanishes when multiline

Tags: bug, full-site

I was reading over my own answer found on this question, [Capacity limitations in the new review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161399/169404), on my Nexus 7 using Chrome when I noticed a bug on the full (*not* mobile) site.

One of my links is only partially underlined. The first portion is fine but the part that gets wrapped to the next line is missing the formatting that represents a link. You can still click it though.

[image: linkbug]

- Android 4.2.1
- Chrome 18.0.1025469