# Permission to do more reviews

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

In the review system you can only review 20 posts in each queue, except the Close Votes queue which gives 40 reviews.

And if you did complete this queue then you can do more review the next day.

So questions raised:

1. Is there any option available that a user can do more than 20 reviews?
2. Is there a moderation privilege for more reviews?
3. Is it available in the near future? Or do we have to contact to moderators for more reviews in a queue?

We all know that moderation is a vital part of SO, I'm very eager to know any positive spotlight for the above concern.

Comment: Your suggestion would have robo-reviewers perfoming 40 useless reviews per day instead of 20. You'd need to suggest some mechanism that would prevent that for this to be in any way workable.

Comment: @RobertLongson: We'r on same boat. I do agree that there are some users that are not in mood of even take a sec to see the problem and just click. So What I suggest is if there is any genuine process of moderation that can help user who really give their time and do a great job in review process _can_ deserve more review queue.

Comment: And how do you propose to sort the wheat from the chaff?

Comment: This needs lot of work. I am not aware of how things work internally in review system, So I can't tell anything about filtering people for review queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as far as I know, there are no plans to increase the reviews per day for ordinary users.

Worth to mention that only on Stack Overflow we have 40 close reviews per day, due to the huge queue in there, on other sites it's the usual 20.

If you really want more, do your best,  and nominate yourself to become a moderator: moderators have unlimited reviews per day.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine there are various reasons behind the decision to limit, one of the most notable ones is from [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102223/230506) by Jeff Atwood:

> We really want vote diversity here, so that's the point of the limits
>   -- if the same 2 folks are vetting all the edits, that's not a sufficient set of eyeballs on those edits

Also, having a higher daily review cap means you open up the doors to more bad reviews, from robo-reviewers, people just aiming for badges, etc. And even those attempting to do good reviews should perhaps take a break - i.e. 20 reviews in a day is enough for anyone really.

This does of course hinder our getting more reviews done by those users who would carry out good reviews with their additional - but such is the world, the few can spoil it for the many because the negative effect of the few outweighs the benefits of the many.

---

> We all know that moderation is a vital part of SO, I'm very eager to
>   know any positive spotlight for the above concern.

What concern?  Is there a *need* for users doing *more* reviews than they can now? Is there a queue with a problem?

Even on Stack Overflow (ignoring close votes) the queues are turned around pretty quickly.
When I see a few hundred reviews in Triage or LQP, 5 or 10 mins later they're all done.

Comment: This. Sometimes it's just time to go outside.