# Where/how to vote on/approve tag wiki edits on a beta site?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, beta-phase

Over on the [Japanese Language & Usage beta](http://japanese.stackexchange.com) site I have currently "1602" reputation and [the privileges page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges) tells me "approve tag wiki edits 100%" (Reputation Required 1500)

Yet I have been unable to find the way to see the edits awaiting voting/approval either by following the "Tags" link or the "review" link (or anywhere else).

So I asked [a support question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-to-get-to-the-place-from-where-i-can-vote-on-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions) on the JL&U meta site. This is the answer I got from a fellow user with higher rep and more privileges than me:

> As far as I am aware, this part is not designed well. There are several ways:
>
> - There is a [list of suggested edits](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits), but the access to this page is limited to the users with [access to the 10k tools](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (≥2,000 rep points during beta, ≥10,000 rep points outside beta). (hippietrail, thank you for the info in the comment.)
> - If you open a tag info page (such as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info)) and it happens to have a pending edit, it shows a link labeled “edit pending.” If you click it, the system gives you options to approve/reject the edit.
> - You can try to randomly access a page with the URL https://japanese.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/nnn where nnn is replaced with a number. If you are lucky, you arrive at a page with approve/reject options. I have used this before I reached 2,000 points, so I know it works, but it is very tiring.
>
> It seems to me that the admins do not want users to approve/reject suggested edits.

So is Tsuyoshi Ito's analysis correct? Is it a badly designed system?
Is it a bug in the difference between beta sites and fully fledged sites where the different amount of rep required to get the "approve tag wiki edits" and "access to moderator tools" privileges? Or have we both missed something?

Answer (score 7):

> - If you open a tag info page (such as this) and it happens to have a pending edit, it shows a link labeled “edit pending.” If you click it, the system gives you options to approve/reject the edit.

This is the intended behavior. SE doesn't want you rushing into approving or rejecting tag wiki edits, because tag wikis get less oversight than regular posts. They trust you not to abuse it, but they don't want you to go in and approve a bunch of edits on the first day. In truth, it's more about contributing to tag wikis themselves—if you spend time improving tag wikis, you're going to encounter the approve/reject buttons. Otherwise, you get the list at mod tools level because you've had even more time to get to know the site.

Comment: And as a result, the edit suggestion queue is always full.

Comment: Here's a [reference question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab) for this.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a look at the suggested edit state on Japanese LU, and see what the problem is.

It seems that you (hippietrail) are busy creating a lot of tag wikis, there are only 4 users + SE mods who are able to approve these edits. This is **good**, you are improving the system. However, there simply are not enough eyes on the queue to keep up with this demand.

Giving you access to the queue would not help in this instance, since you are the main person clogging it up AND you can not approve your own edits. You also seem to be the only person in the 1500-2000 rep bracket.

I changed the queue size on Japanese to 50 pending edits (this will allow for 25 tag wikis) which should be ample.

By-design we reduce access to the queue, cause we want the most seasoned users reviewing it. If you happen across and edit that is blocking you, we allow you to approve. Accessing the edit queue, is a privilege.

Comment: Yes I knew I couldn't approve my own edits but I got the new privelege and wanted to try it out and see if anyone else had joined in the tag wiki editing... which they have now (-: