# Can I review pending edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Is there an area to review pending suggested edits from users with less than 2k reputation? As far as I know, I have to visit a question directly to even confirm that it has a pending edit.

Sometimes when using [the Review site](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), I want to review edits, but there is no edit review tool; consequentially, I would have to resort to clicking every link on the main page until I came across pending edits if I were that determined.

This seems like it should be a common question, but I can't seem to find a similar question. In my missing privileges, I see [Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), attainable at 10k reputation, but from the description on that page, whether an edit review tool is included seems ambiguous. And I doubt that a list of suggested edits would be restricted to 10k users when approval votes are given to 2k users.

Comment: Even though you doubt it, it is true. :-) In reached 10k this week, and got a new tab on the Review section.

Comment: Here's a related question about [tag edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95321/) where it was said that there is no available list to see proposed tag edits without the moderator tools.  The same answer _might_ apply to regular edits.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits .  If this works for you, you are allowed, otherwise you will have to wait until 10k reputation.

Comment: It's mentioned in the [suggested edits FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work): “The user interface that lists all pending edits is only available to developers, moderators and 10k users.”

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is a way (although somewhat tedious) to review pending edits even with less than 10,000 reputation points or when not having the [Heart of Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Gold_%28spaceship%29#Heart_of_Gold) nearby.

1. Find the end of the edit queue. Use `https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/X`, where X is an integer. If X is past the end, the result will be "Page Not Found" and if not, "Suggested Edit". Do a binary search to find it. On 2011-06-14 the end of the queue was `https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/60511` and on 2011-07-04T02:09:00+02 it was https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/70489.
2. Find suggested edits not approved or rejected (pending) by lowering the ID number, for example, 70488, 70487, 70486, etc. When one is found, click the link on the top of the page to open the post and take part in the approval process.

Comment: As of 2012-03-21, http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/224730 was close to the end.

Comment: As of 2012-04-20T20:15:00Z: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/244819

Comment: As of 2012-05-05T22:15:00Z: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/257420

Comment: As of 2012-06-09T08:15:00Z: [stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283902](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283902)

Comment: As of 2012-07-07T08:46:50Z: stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/309576

Comment: 2015-12-11, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/545907

Comment: As of 2018-06-08 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/650151

Comment: As of 2019-04-05 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/721269

Comment: As of 2019-12-24 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/821269

Comment: As of 2021-06-15 [stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15885814](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15885814)

Answer (score 4):

as Paŭlo said:

> Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits . If this works for you, you are allowed, otherwise you will have to wait until 10k reputation.

Reviewing all pending suggested edits is one of the 10k user rep privileges.

Comment: The reputation requirement has been lowered to 2k for reviewing edits.