# Approving edits without the required 5000 rep

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

It seems that I was able to *vote/approve* a suggested edit without having the required 5000 rep. Is this a feature I wasn't aware of?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9035784/1101070) post and in the middle of refreshing and commenting on it, I noticed the `edit` link under the post change to:

```
edit(1)
```

Or something of that sort, I don't remember the details exactly. Then being the curious person that I am, I of course clicked on it and up came this dialog asking me to approve/reject/etc. I couldn't resist approving it *just to see if it would work*, and low and behold, I got [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/189403) for approving it.

[image]

I unfortunately don't have screenshots of the edit link changing or the approve/reject dialog. Are users below 5000 rep allowed to approve/reject edits?

Comment: You need _2000_ rep to be able to review suggested edits, the same amount to be able to do regular edits.  You apparently have enough rep to do so.  `2031 >= 2000`

Comment: @JeffMercado Reading through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) page, I was under the impression you could only do that at 5000 rep.

Comment: 5000 is when you gain access to "review" the list. You can *do* the approve/reject at 2k

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ohh.. I see, bummer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So obvious follow-up question, is there any query I can run that will give me a list of all the edits in the system waiting for approval?

Comment: In other news, "approved 1 edit suggestion__s__"?! I'd post about this but I'm allergic to giant letters.

Comment: You **can** find suggested edits to approve/reject. Look at the accepted answer on my question: [Can I review pending edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97363/162322).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 2,000 rep to [make/approve edits to regular posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), 5,000 is for [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) [edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Comment: You missed something. 5000 is also when you gain access to the suggested edits queue.