# Could a list of pending suggested edits be added upon reaching 5k or 7.5k rep?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why set the bar so high for viewing 'suggested edits' review tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab)

Until today, I had never approved a suggested edit before.  [But I just did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1261).  I totally thought this was a bug.  I had no idea that [any users with edit privileges can approve suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284).
Now I see that [this answer in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) states explicitly that:

> Users with 10k reputation are notified in the top bar if there are any pending edits awaiting their approval.

Considering the [recent concern over moderators not clearing sufficient numbers of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/should-stack-overflow-moderators-have-a-standard-of-duty):

### Could 5k (or 7.5k) users have a list of the pending suggested edits??

I've only got 4K rep here on Meta, but I'd happily approve / disapprove / improve these edit suggestions to reduce the burden on the higher rep users & moderators. If I had a central page to work from, this would be *much* easier.

Comment: I sure wish I could see the page for them on SO.

Comment: IMHO, approval privileges should be based on approved edits, not rep.  I'm at 1.1K on SO, but I have [quite a few approved edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/467090/john?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions).

Comment: @John: Then soon, you will be able to make edits *without* requiring approval. That's why we give points for approved suggested edits: to get you one step closer to full editing privileges.

Comment: Suggested edits get cleared off relatively fast and it never reaches the numbers that the flags do.  Considering edits could be handled by non-mods and flags really can't, there's plenty of eyes handling suggested edits IMHO.  [You've gotta earn you way to view them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab).